# Assign a value of 0 or 1 using the logit value of a logistic regression model

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

Let's assume we have a bernoulli variable and one continuous explanatory variable. After running the model, with the logit value at hand ( let's say its 1.3 which means that we have 30% greater chance of success than failure) i want to assign a single value of 0 and 1, since i'm doing a bayesian prediction.

Which is the most sufficient scientific way of the doing the above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The most general way is to define a utility function (benefit or loss) for assigning the correct or incorrect category, then make the assignment which has greater expected utility, with the expectation being taken with respect to the probability computed by your classification model.

Assigning categories via a utility function is discussed in many books on classification problems, e.g. "Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks" by Brian Ripley. A more general description of making decisions to maximize expected utility is "Making Hard Decisions" by Robert Clemen.

Comment: Well-written textbooks with clear demonstration of the concepts of decision theory in classification problems. I  appreciate the directions.